# grep using wildcard .* but ignore whitespaces

Tags: grep

I need to find all instances of `&var[0]` in a C++ code. Using `grep -r "&.*\[0\]" .` found those but also `int& aaa = bbb[0];`. How to make grep wildcard `.*` to avoid whitespaces at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `"&\w*\[0\]"`? `\w` identifies "word characters", ie `[A-Za-z_]`, so it should do what you're looking for.

EDIT: Elevating this excellent point from the comments:

> \w is nonstandard, so it'd be safer to replace it with something like [[:alnum:]_]